# htaccess force ssl for a particular domain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

How do I force SSL for a particular domain currently I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is working, however I have several add on domains on my hosting and when I try to access the other add-on domains, the add-on domains are also forced to use SSL.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampledomain\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exampledomain\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.examplemydomain\.org\/" [R=301,L]
```

But it is giving me an infinite loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} exampledomain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.examplemydomain.org%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: That space between the caret and the destination address is rather important ;-) I learned a thing, partially by trial and error.

Comment: @anubhava how about subdomains? for example: sub.exampledomain.com

Comment: @MortezaRajabi: Then you can use: `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: @anubhava, I need it for a specific domain. There are other domains that coming to my website, but I only need to force SSL for a specific subdomain.

Comment: You will still need `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.exampledomain.org` condition before this `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're doing 2 different things here. You're adding a `www` when one is missing, and you're forcing SSL when it isn't used. So there's 2 different conditions and either one being true should force a redirect. That means you want to use the `[OR]` flag, but the way you were using it breaks if the request is *already SSL*. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampledomain\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.examplemydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.){0,1}exampledomain\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.examplemydomain\.org\/" [R=301,L]
```